# how to run gambit-c

Tags: scheme, gambit

It's late and I should go to bed and maybe that's why I can't figure this out. I'm on a fedora-13 machine and I just ran

```
yum install gambit-c
```

I installed it because I want to follow along in a schemed text book.

but now that it's installed, how do I start the scheme interpreter??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks from the RPM listing that the binaries are named `gsi`, `gsix`, and `gsc`, all in `/usr/bin`.  I suspect that `gsi` is the interpreter.

Comment: awesome. thank you. How did you look at the RPM listing? just 'ls /usr/bin'?

Comment: Google search for "gambit-c rpm"; a file listing is the first hit.

Comment: You can also do `rpm -ql gambit-c` for a file listing for an installed package.

Answer (score 1):

For more details, there's also the [manual entry](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~gambit/doc/gambit-c.html#GSI) for gsi.

BTW: I don't know about the Fedora RPM, but I found that the Ubuntu repository's Gambit-C was quite outdated (4.0-ish), with missing features like simple compilation of stand-alone executables. The most recent version is 4.6. If your RPM's version is a few decimal places behind, I'd suggest just installing from source; it's a pretty standard configure -> make -> make install sequence. Just remember the following option when [running configure](http://dynamo.iro.umontreal.ca/~gambit/wiki/index.php/Configure_script_options):

```
./configure --enable-single-host
```

This speeds things up quite a bit.